# How to get output in integer instead of ASCII code value

Tags: c, char, ascii, integer-promotion

I am executing this program
Output is 104 in ASCII Code values.
It is giving value in ASCII value but how can i get output in number

```
void main()

{
    char ch1 , ch2, sum;

    ch1 = '2';
    ch2 = '6';
    sum = ch1+ch2;
    printf("sum = %d ", sum);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Can you describe the output you are expecting?  Are you looking for it to print 8?

Comment: You ask "how can i get output in number" - but `104` is a number. Is it not the number you were expecting? What were you expecting? Surely not `8`? `'2'` is an ASCII character with the decimal value 50, while `'6'` is an ASCII character with decimal value 54. 50 + 54 == 104. If you're intending to add `2` and `6` then you should have `ch1 = 2; ch2 = 6;` so that you assign the decimal number values to your variables instead of the ASCII character codes.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the expression

```
sum = ch1 - '0' + ch2;
```

and then

```
printf("sum = %c ", sum);
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char ch1 , ch2, sum;

    ch1 = '2';
    ch2 = '6';
    sum = ch1 -'0' + ch2;

    printf( "sum = %c\n ", sum );
    //            ^^^ 

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
sum = 8
```

Another approach is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char ch1 , ch2, sum;

    ch1 = '2';
    ch2 = '6';
    sum = ch1 -'0' + ch2 - '0';

    printf( "sum = %d\n ", sum );
    //            ^^^ 

    return 0;
}
```

As for your code then in this code snippet

```
ch1 = '2';
ch2 = '6';
sum = ch1+ch2;
```

the expression `ch1+ch2` is evaluated like `50 + 54` (if there is used the ASCII coding of characters)

Answer (score 0):

I think `%c` is the specifier you are looking for.

Comment: That is how you print a character, but one of the issues is the fact that arithmetic is being done with characters, not the integer values they represent.

Comment: Ah you really wanted to print the `8`.. thought I got your question but well.. I didn't.